# Query to extract data from reference table as per the column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario which includes two Tables
`Table1 (ID INT, Name VARCHAR)`
`Values(1, 'A')`
`Values(2,'B')`
`Values(3,'C')`

`Table2 (Val VARCHAR(4), Name VARCHAR)`
`Values('V01','A')`
`Value('V02' , 'A')`
`Value('V01', 'B')`
`Value('V04' , 'B')`
`Value('V03', 'B')`
`Value('V02' , 'C')`

NAME column is primary key IN table1 and referenced in Table2

I want ID and NAME in output such that only that Name from Table1 would come which have values 'V01' and 'V02' in Table2

Output should be
`ID | Name`
`1  | A`

Kindly suggest a solution using analytical function and/or without using Common Table Expression (CTE)

One solution which I found is 
`WITH CTE AS (SELECT *, CASE VAL WHEN 'V01' THEN 0 WHEN 'V02' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS CAS FROM table2) SELECT t1.ID, t1.NAME FROM table1 t1 JOIN (SELECT NAME,SUM(CAS) AS "SumC" FROM CTE GROUP BY NAME) AS "NewT" ON t1.NAME = NewT.NAME WHERE NewT.SumC =0`

Comment: If that's part of your question it would be better to add it there rather than as a comment.

Comment: Don't add code in comments. [edit] your question.

Comment: Thanks, added code in question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a CTE or analytic functions, you can use aggregates:

```
select t1.id, t1.name
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.name = t1.name
where t2.val in ('V01', 'V02')
group by t1.id, t1.name
having count(t2.val) = 2;

        ID N
---------- -
         1 A
```

If there could be multiple matches then the condition can be:

```
having count(distinct t2.val) = 2;
```

This joins the tables, only looking for the two values you're interested in; and then counts how may of those values it actually matched on. You want both, so the count has to match the number of values you were looking for.

You could also use a separate `exists` clause for each value you're looking for, and the logic is perhaps more intuitive:

```
select t1.id, t1.name
from table1 t1
where exists (
  select null
  from table2 t2
  where t2.name = t1.name
  and t2.val = 'V01'
)
and exists (
  select null
  from table2 t2
  where t2.name = t1.name
  and t2.val = 'V02'
);
```

but that hits the second table multiple times and doesn't scale well, either in terms or performance or code readability/maintenance.